# how to move circle as my location changed in Google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application in this i draw a circle on map

I want that as my location changed circle also moves as my location changed

if any one know please help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: It's very easy... Draw a New `Circle` every time on `Location Changed(.....)`

Comment: i draw circle but location is update but circle is not moving

Comment: Use Service to do that

Comment: show me your code first.

Comment: private void goToCurrentLocation() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
  if (currentLocation == null) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Current Location is'nt Avialable",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
   LatLng ll = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),
     currentLocation.getLongitude());
   float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;
   CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
     DEFAULTZOOM);
   mMap.animateCamera(update);

   drawcircle(ll);
  }

 }

Comment: this is my code for finding current location and draw circle

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    drawMarker(location);
}


private void drawMarker(Location location)
{
    googleMap.clear();
    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(currentPosition)
    .snippet("Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + " Lng:"+ location.getLongitude())
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
    .title("ME"));

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).zoom(15f).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}
```

Comment: thanku so much its working but i want to know that if my device is move draw a path on google map automatically on map if you know please tell me

Comment: Whenever the onLocationChanged method is called (means new location update) the old marker is cleared from the map and new marker is created on the current location.

Comment: i want to draw path line on map not marker as user move with his device

Answer (score 1):

To move the marker, you may store the marker in a variable when you add to map. And when you want to move it, call the api marker.setPosition(position_where_you_want_to_move). This will not require the map to be cleared everytime location is retrieved